# CVS checkout specific commit

Tags: cvs

Then I want to checkout specific commit in git I do:

```
git log # find out commit name
git checkout commit_name
```

What should I do with CVS?

Comment: cvs does not have the idea of a global commit id like git does. cvs is file based, so each file will have its own revision id. You can manually give the whole module a symbolic name using `cvs tag` and then check that out at any time, but that requires planning. Based on yout git example, I don't think that's what you are after.

Comment: @BurhanAli, thanks for comment, can you help me this out: so if I want to be able checkout in future each commit, is it normal to tag it each time? CVS users try to not get in situations like when needed particular commit? What workflow do they have?

Comment: CVS is really old and lacks many of the features of a modern revision control system (such as the things in git that you are used to) so I wouldn't recommend using it for anything new. Tagging is fine for taking snapshots of the code (eg. a version, a safe place before making major changes, etc). What exactly are you trying to do? Why are you wanting to back to a specific set of commits?

Comment: @BurhanAli, I agree with recommendation not using for anything new. My task was to prepare bugfix.patch for specific version. No tag was committed, but was known release was done after updating changelog file. Looking through log and checkout by date helped me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can not find any command to output commit list for whole module and checkout by commit_id.
`cvs log` will output commit comments for each file separately. Maybe it's obvious, but let it be here:

```
cvs log # find date corresponding to commit
cvs checkout -D "commit_date"
```